# Ionic2/Ionic3 How to Include the non-native plugin, then call js file to use the plugin function in ts file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am the tiro of ionic2. My project is about using bluetooth to connect some devices. I using a non-native connect bluetooth plugin to handle my work, but the plugin only use on ionic1, i want to use on ionic3.

1. The first question is: Is it possible to use ionic1 plugin on ionic3?

There are two js files on the plugin(`a.js` and `b.js`) and i checked the `plugin.xml` the clobbers target of js module is `window.a` and the `b.js` is calling `a.js`

Example `plugin.xml` code below

```
...
<js-module src="www/a.js" name="A">
    <clobbers target="window.a" />
</js-module>
...
```

`a.js` file code:

```
cordova.define("cordova-data.a", function(require, exports, module) {
    "use strict";
    ...
    module.exports = {
        isCorrect: function (success, fail){
            cordova.exec(success, fail, 'aPlugin', 'isCorrect', []);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

So i only need to include `b.js` file on my home page(`home.ts`).

Here the the code of `b.js` file:

```
var a = angular.module('a', []).factory('$a', ['$q', '$timeout', function($q, $timeout){
    var error = {
        error: "failed",
        message: "failed to get data"
    }

    ...
    var isCorrect = function() {
        var q = $q.defer();
        if (window.a === undefined) {
            q.reject(error);
        } else {
            window.a.isCorrect(
                function(ob) {
                    q.notify(ob);
                },
                function(ob) {
                    q.reject(ob);
                }
            );
        }
        return q.promise;
    }
    ...
    return {
        isCorrect: isCorrect
    };
}]);
```

Here the code in my `home.ts` file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
declare var a: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

constructor(
      public navCtrl: NavController,
) {
      console.log(a);
}
```

Here the code in my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    ...
    <script src="assets/js/a.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
<body>
```

When i run it on the browser, it return the Object like this:

```
{_invokeQueue: Array(1), _configBlocks: Array(0), _runBlocks: Array(0), requires: Array(0), name: "a", …}
```

2. The second question is how can i call the isCorrect function in angular.module function? Or any way to call the isCorrect function of `a.js`?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: b.js looks like angularjs(v1).. you cannot include that as ionic2 + uses angular (v2+).. not compatible

Comment: @Suraj Rao Thanks for your helping. I see...how can i include the plugin and use the isCorrect function of a.js file without using b.js file on ionic3?